# Vue js e Axios não identifica resposta JSON da API

Tags: json, vue.js, axios, response

Tenho o seguinte código para buscar dados de uma API via POST, recebo o resultado do JSON (pois consigo escreve-lo no console. Porém não consigo recurepar os valores para preencher o Array dos elementos Vue.

```
// Get Pipelines
const getPipelines = new Vue({
    el: '#top-pipelines',
    data: {
        pipelines: []
    },
    mounted() {
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http:..xpto.../getpipelines',
            data: {
                orgId: "ORGIDXPTO",
                pipelineId: "19",
                dateFrom: "2017-11-01",
                dateTo: "2017-11-31"
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
               console.log(response);
               this.pipelines = response.json;
        })
    }
});
```

tentei também "this.pipelines = response.data;"

Importante dizer que meu JSON de resposta não tem uma linha de cabeçalho antes do array de objetos (veja abaixo).

```
[
    {
        "id_pipeline": "NOME_PIPELINE_XPTO",
        "id_org": "ORGIDXPTO",
        "name": "Nome Pipeline",
        "active": "1"
    },
    {
        "id_pipeline": "NOME_PIPELINE_XPTO",
        "id_org": "ORGIDXPTO",
        "name": "Nome Pipeline",
        "active": "1"
    },
    {
        "id_pipeline": "NOME_PIPELINE_XPTO",
        "id_org": "ORGIDXPTO",
        "name": "Nome Pipeline",
        "active": "1"
    },
    {
        "id_pipeline": "NOME_PIPELINE_XPTO",
        "id_org": "ORGIDXPTO",
        "name": "Nome Pipeline",
        "active": "1"
    },
    {
        "id_pipeline": "NOME_PIPELINE_XPTO",
        "id_org": "ORGIDXPTO",
        "name": "Nome Pipeline",
        "active": "1"
    }
]
```

Alguma dica?

Comment: Sendo que sua resposta é um array você está tentando acessar `response.json` como `json` sendo uma propriedade de `response` ele deve te retornar um erro por tentar acessar uma propriedade nomeada de um array. Como no Axios você não define que a resposta a ser recebida é um json você recebe texto e não JSON, portanto, tente usar `this.pipelines = JSON.parse(response);` para deserializar

Comment: Oi Huxley, testaste a sugestão do @RômuloGabrielRodrigues?

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão Rômulo, tentei usar e também não funcionou. Consegui corrigir definindo os headers `headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
         }` e também recuperei o response assim `.then(response => {
   this.pipelines = response.data
  })`Abraço

Comment: O que dá no console se fizeres `console.log(typeof response, response);`?

Answer (score 0):

Voce deve usar

> response.data

De acordo com a documentação do axios, essa é o modelo de resposta:

```
{
  // `data` is the response that was provided by the server
  data: {},

  // `status` is the HTTP status code from the server response
  status: 200,

  // `statusText` is the HTTP status message from the server response
  statusText: 'OK',

  // `headers` the headers that the server responded with
  // All header names are lower cased
  headers: {},

  // `config` is the config that was provided to `axios` for the request
  config: {},

  // `request` is the request that generated this response
  // It is the last ClientRequest instance in node.js (in redirects)
  // and an XMLHttpRequest instance the browser
  request: {}
}
```